# What is the different between cast and safe cast operators and null

Tags: kotlin

Lets say I have 2 expressions:

```
val x: Int? = null as Int?
```

and

```
val x: Int? = null as? Int?
```

What is the different between them?

Why the first one is unsafe cast?

Comment: The first one is unsafe because it will throw an exception if the cast fails (although in this special case it will always succeed).

Comment: Also, `null as? Int` is equivalent to `null as? Int?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practical terms the unsafe cast throws an exception when the cast fails and the safe cast converts to `null` when the cast operation fails.

```
val x1: Int? = 1.0 as? Int?
println(x1)
```

This prints:

```
null
```

And this code here:

```
val x: Int? = 1.0 as Int?
```

throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```